# How to change the button image inside the UICollectionViewCell using for loop in ios

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]Am new to xcode.In below screenshoot in indexpath.row=0 to indexpath.row =4 am having x button and from indexpath.row=5 to indexpath.row=8 having + button.How should i write for loop condition to those buttons.Any help is appreciable.

Here is my code.

ViewController.m

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    RACollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    cell.imageView.frame = cell.bounds;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_photosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.imageView];

        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];

        [cell.imageView addSubview:btn];

        if (indexPath.item == 0)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_dele_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

       else if (indexPath.item == 1)
       {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_dele_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }

        else if (indexPath.item == 2)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_dele_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        else if (indexPath.item == 3)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_dele_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if (indexPath.item == 4)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_dele_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if (indexPath.item == 5)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_add_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if (indexPath.item == 6)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_add_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else if (indexPath.item == 7)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_add_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else if (indexPath.item == 8)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_add_photo"];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        if (iPhone5)
        {
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(82, 82, 18, 18);
        }
        else if (iPhone6)
        {
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(101, 100, 18, 18);

        }
        else if (iPhone6Plus)
        {
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(112, 112, 18, 18);

        }
        else
        {
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(80, 80, 18, 18);
        }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you just want to set the right button image, you could use NSString *imageName = indexPath.row < 5 ? @"ic_dele_photo" : @"ic_add_photo"; and assign the image to the button. Much more important is that you don't hard code the positions of your button, but use auto layout instead.